# A general expression for $\ln i$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, complex-numbers, logarithms, discrete-logarithms

Is there a general expression for $\ln i$, that can give all different values of $\ln i$, depending upon an input value? I know of them is $i\pi/2$, so is there a formula to find others too?

Answer (score 0):

$\ln \iota=\ln{\vert \iota \vert}+\iota \arg(\iota )$ where  $(\arg(\iota)=2n{\pi}+{\pi}/2)$
this is definition of $\ln \iota$